# Low pass filtering effect on accuracy of power measurement

Tags: adc, low-pass, power-measurement

I'm planning on measuring consumed power (for an e-bike) by sampling current and voltage with an ADC and digitally approximating the power based on the obtained values.

I need to pick a sampling rate for the ADC to measure the current.

Based on on the current waveform that I've measure with an oscilloscope I think 1 Msps should be enough but maybe I can get away with a lower sampling rate low pass filtering the current sense voltage before the ADC.

How will the low pass filtering down to 50 kHz and sampling at 100 kHz affect the measurement accuracy of the energy consumed over time if my target is accurate within +/-5%? (I'm not worried about instantaneous power.)

(The below was measured **between the battery and controller** across a wire shunt amplified with an op-amp from 0 to full throttle with no load. I am not sure if the measurement setup is correct.)

[image: e-bike current from 0 to full throttle, no load, 500 ms per division]

[image: e-bike current no load, stable at full throttle, 5 ms per division]

[image: e-bike current no load, stable at full throttle, 1 ms per division]

Comment: You'd want to low pass filter beneath the nyquist frequency to prevent aliasing.

Comment: Sorry, I got the 2 numbers the wrong way around, the sampling should 2x the highest frequency of-course, corrected.

Comment: What errors can you tolerate due to battery loss in voltage when only current is measured?  Can you give a spec for desired Power Accuracy and max time interval needed?  These answers define the optimal solution

Comment: @sunnyskyguy-ee75, battery voltage loss is significant (13s Li-Ion battery, from 54.6V to 39V) so I'll need to measure the voltage as well, but it won't change anywhere as fast as the current, so I'm not worried about that. The time interval would be several hours (e.g. 2 hours) and I would consider 5% a good accuracy.

Comment: I've not actually measured the voltage with a scope but I assume the battery being a low resistance source the fluctuations in current shouldn't affect the voltage significantly, but I can sample the voltage at the same rate as the current with a second ADC if needed.

Comment: What is the max sample interval for 5% needed , considering you can average over any interval with a LPF. But actually V(t) error may be bigger (~5%) than you think if 13S1P cell is  13 * 50mΩ * I = ΔV

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75, the interval could be 1s or more, not critical. So assuming the voltage is constant is there a low pass filter pass filter could serve as a kind of an integrator, right? As to the voltage it's quite a big change of 0.65V per amp considering the current fluctuations are several amps. Could I do an analog multiplier of the voltage and current signals and then low-pass filter that? (don't know what I'm talking about here :)

Comment: Forgot that it's 13S6P, so maybe the voltage won't change that much after all.

Comment: You can calibrate the battery drop with a CC pulse every so often to characterize it then use an algorithm to compute estimated Power from this or actually measure ΔV and then apply a correction factor easier than multiplying. But all are possible ways.

Comment: If I assume a good design has RdsOn (FET)<  ESR(bat) << DCR of motors then  ΔV will be accurate. But if not 12S6P is equivalent to  2S and a good cell is 25 mΩ while a typical cell is 50 mΩ and a weak cell is >100mΩ so 2S is 2x those values.  Then measure DCR of main motors then compare with RdsOn

Comment: So if  **RdsOn (FET)< ESR(bat) << DCR of motors** and ESR is good then 50mΩ *5A =250mV and 0.25/40V is ~0.6%  but if not true it can rise to 5% in bad designs. So it depends on ratio of (ESR+2RdsOn)/DCR (motors equiv)

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75, thanks for the tips! (I'll have to measure the voltage with a scope as well I suppose under some mechanical load and see how it changes with current).

Comment: DCR of motor coil with DMM is the max surge current when starting V/DCR=Imax  which is 10x rated continuous current @ xx 'C  BTW your scope says 4V. Your current sensor should be 100mV worst case. The load only stretches out Imax then reduces with rising RPM to 10% Imax (Avg) at max RPM

Comment: My understanding was the current is limited by the controller resulting in the plateau at the start so it doesn't reach V/DCR. As to the voltage it's the amplified voltage, don't remember the amplification factor now, measured this a couple of months ago, was interested in the waveform, not the absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your scope correctly the fundamental frequency of that hash is about 2kHz, and it doesn't have a lot of sharp edges.  That suggests that you've got frequency content up to maybe 10kHz at most.  Depending on how aggressively you want to filter, you could probably get away with less than 100kHz, but 100kHz (and an appropriate anti-aliasing filter) would do it.

To get the most accurate power reading you want to sample voltage and current simultaneously, multiply, and average.

[This article](http://wescottdesign.com/articles/Sampling/sampling.pdf) is really directed more toward debunking common misconceptions about sampling, but should have some guidance about how to select an anti-aliasing filter to go with that signal and a 100kHz sampling rate.

Comment: Can you say that in 25 words or less how Sampling rate and filter affects % error by Fs/Fbw ratio

Comment: The more you filter, the more you get rid of unwanted noise, unwanted aliasing products, and (possibly) wanted signals.  It depends on the input signal and what you're doing with it.  There's a *reason* this kind of stuff tends to get done by the senior people.

Comment: I was hoping you would used quantitative words or the formula...

Comment: Not in 25 words or less, and certainly not for a mostly-undefined input signal and a mostly-undefined usage.  The whole issue of sampling and anti-aliasing filtering is treated in depth in a lot of places -- usually in book-length form, or articles whose **abstracts** significantly exceed 25 words.

Comment: For sampling a 1 KHz sinusoid 2 Ksps is enough but then how do I reconstruct the integral, not straightforward. Sampling at 20 Ksps provided the signal doesn't contain anything significant above 1 KHz I could get away with simple trapezoid area approximations for the integral and get a decent accuracy. So maybe it is easier with oversampling in this respect if I sample at 1MHz, not sure how difficult it would be to reconstruct the integral from 2f sample rate samples.